# Creating a custom comparator in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

**Background:**

I got asked this question today in a online practice interview and I had a hard time figuring out a custom comparator to sort. Here is the question

**Question:**

> Implement a document scanning function wordCountEngine, which receives a string document and returns a list of all unique words in it and their number of occurrences, sorted by the number of occurrences in a descending order. If two or more words have the same count, they should be sorted according to their order in the original sentence. Assume that all letters are in english alphabet. You function should be case-insensitive, so for instance, the words “Perfect” and “perfect” should be considered the same word.
>
> The engine should strip out punctuation (even in the middle of a word) and use whitespaces to separate words.
>
> Analyze the time and space complexities of your solution. Try to optimize for time while keeping a polynomial space complexity.
>
> Examples:
>
> input:  document = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only
>                       get Perfect by practice. just practice!"
>
> output: [ ["practice", "3"], ["perfect", "2"],
>             ["makes", "1"], ["youll", "1"], ["only", "1"], 
>             ["get", "1"], ["by", "1"], ["just", "1"] ]

**My idea:**

The first think I wanted to do was first get the string without punctuation and all in lower case into a vector of strings. Then I used an `unordered_map` container to store the string and a count of its occurrence. Where I got stuck was creating a custom comparator to make sure that if I have a string that has the same count then I would sort it based on its precedence in the actual given string.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


struct cmp
{
  bool operator()(std::string& word1, std::string& word2)
  {

  }
};

vector<vector<string>> wordCountEngine( const string& document ) 
{
  // your code goes here
  // Step 1
  auto doc = document;
  std::string str;
  remove_copy_if(doc.begin(), doc.end(), std::back_inserter(str), 
                     std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct));
  for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
  istream_iterator<std::string> end;
  std::vector<std::string> vec(begin, end);

  // Step 2
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;
  for(auto word : vec)
    m[word]++;

  // Step 3
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> result;
  for(auto it : m)
  {
    result.push_back({it.first, std::to_string(it.second)});
  }


  return result;

}

int main() {

  std::string document = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only get Perfect by practice. just practice!";
  auto result = wordCountEngine(document);
  for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < result[0].size(); ++j)
    {
      std::cout << result[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If anyone can help me with learning how to build a custom comparator for this code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try using `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` as the `result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>`, with each pair representing one word and the number of occurrences of that word in the sequence. Using a vector will help to maintain the order of the original sequence when two or more words have the same count. Finally sort by occurrences.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> wordCountEngine(const std::string& document)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> words;
    std::istringstream ss(document);
    std::string word;

    //Loop through words in sequence
    while (getline(ss, word, ' '))
    {
        //Convert to lowercase
        std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), tolower);

        //Remove punctuation characters
        auto it = std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c) { return !isalpha(c); });
        word.erase(it, word.end());

        //Find this word in the result vector
        auto pos = std::find_if(words.begin(), words.end(),
            [&word](const std::pair<std::string, int>& p) { return p.first == word; });
        if (pos == words.end()) {
            words.push_back({ word, 1 });  //Doesn't occur -> add it
        }
        else {
            pos->second++;                 //Increment count
        }
    }

    //Sort vector by word occurrences
    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [](const std::pair<std::string, int>& p1, const std::pair<std::string, int>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

    //Convert to vector<vector<string>>
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> result;
    result.reserve(words.size());

    for (auto& p : words)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> v = { p.first, std::to_string(p.second) };
        result.push_back(v);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string document = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only get Perfect by practice. just practice!";
    auto result = wordCountEngine(document);
    for (auto& word : result)
    {
        std::cout << word[0] << ", " << word[1] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
practice, 3
perfect, 2
makes, 1
youll, 1
only, 1
get, 1
by, 1
just, 1

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I've added some comments to help explain it.

Comment: I think for this test case your code will fail: std::string document =  "Practice makes perfect, you'll get perfecT by practice. just practice! just just just!!";

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx For that test case the output is: just, 4; practice 3; perfect, 2; makes, 1;  youll, 1; get, 1; by, 1. That's correct. However, if remove one 'just' then 'practice' will come first.

Comment: Could you help me convert the vector<pair<string,int> > to a vector<vector<string>> because when I try that it fails the test case I mentioned.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I've updated the code to return a `vector<vector<string>>`.

Answer (score 1):

In step2, try this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<std::string, int>, int>> m;
```

Here, the pair stores the string and this index of its occurance, and the vector stores the pair and the count of its occurances. Write a logic, to sort according to the count first and then if the counts are same, then sort it according to the position of its occurance.

```
bool sort_vector(const std::pair<const std::pair<std::string,int>,int> &a, const std::pair<const std::pair<std::string,int>,int> &b)
{
    if(a.second==b.second)
    {
        return a.first.second<b.first.second
        // This will make sure that if the no of occurances of each string is same, then it will be sorted according to the position of the string
    }
    return a.second>b.second
    //This will make sure that the strings are sorted in the order to return the string having higher no of occurances first.
}
```

You have to write a logic to count the number of occurrences and the index of occurrence of each word in the string.

Comment: Great suggestion! Would I use a custom comparator that takes two pairs<std:string, int> to do the logic part?

Comment: I guess that would not work since I need to also know the number of counts as well. I guess a function should that does this will work.

Comment: Yea I still a bit stuck if you can provide some code assistance that would be helpful

Comment: you can't sort an unordered_map directly, you have to put those into a vector. So i want to upgrade my answer a bit. USe std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>,int> m;

Comment: That is sort of a long confusing container to work with, I will give it a try

Comment: Can you help me with this part:

Comment: std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<std::string, int>, int>> m;
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
  {
    m[{make_pair(vec[i], i)}]++;
  }

Comment: The container is quite confusing to work with for me